# JavaScript show and hide elements on click

Tags: javascript

Please excuse my ignorance, I have no idea what I'm doing, but I'm trying.

I attempted to figure it out by searching, but it has only yielded a functional result in jQuery. Since this is such a small section, I think it would be better to just use plain vanilla JavaScript instead of loading the entire jQuery library.

Does anyone know how/if I can accomplish the same functionality below, *but with only normal **JavaScript***? Basically what I am trying to do is when "butt1" is clicked, the unordered list "links" will become hidden and the div "box1" will be shown:

```
<html> 
<head> 
   <title>qwerty</title> 
   <style type="text/css"> 
      .box1 {background: red;}
   </style> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $("#butt1").live("click", show_box1);
      function show_box1(event) {
          $("#links").css("display", "none");
          $(".box1").css("display", "inline");            
      }
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <ul id="links"> 
      <li id="butt1"><a href="#">blah</a></li> 
      <li id="butt2"><a href="#">blah</a></li> 
      <li id="butt3"><a href="#">blah</a></li> 
   </ul> 
   <div class="box1" style="display: none;">You clicked butt1!</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here's a link to the above as a working example: http://jsbin.com/umitef/4/ -- this is the functionality I want replicated.

My extended thanks to anyone who takes a moment.. :-)

Comment: If you're using jQuery for other parts of the site already, or will be, you may as well use it for this.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `getElementById` to select an element using an `id` (equivalent to `$("#something")`), and `getElementsByClassName` to select elements based on class name (equivalent to `$(".something")`), and you can use the `style` property to set the `display` style (equivalent to the jQuery `.css` method):

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box1");
document.getElementById("butt1").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("links").style.display = "none";
    for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Note however that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in older versions of IE, which is why jQuery can be useful even for small things - it shortens the code and irons out all the annoying little browser differences.

Also, one major difference between the above code and your jQuery is the use of the `.live` jQuery method, which monitors the DOM and attaches the event to any element matching the selector, whether it was in the DOM already or it gets added in the future. With the above code, if there is not already an element with `id` "butt1" in the DOM when the code runs, you will get a TypeError, because `getElementById` will return `null`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#links").css("display", "none");
```

Could become:

```
document.getElementById('links').style.display = 'none';
```

Realistically, loading jQuery makes a lot of sense since you're doing it from the Google CDN. A lot of sites use that so there is a good probability that at some point at least some of your users have already downloaded it. Plus, jQuery compressed is a very small download. So much so that the readability of jQuery style code is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, while the easiest way is to do it jQuery style you can still replicate that functionality in Javascript.

The key here is the **getElementById** function to grab the specific element you want to manipulate and then you simply set the **element.style.display** property to **'none'** when you want to hide it and **'block'** or **'inline'** when you want to show it (depending on the context)

Here is my crack at it...

```
<head>
<title>qwerty</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
    #box1 {background: red;}
    #box2 {background: blue;}
    #box3 {background: yellow;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('links');
    var box = document.getElementById(id);
    if(ul.style.display == 'none')
    {
        ul.style.display = 'block';
        box.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        ul.style.display = 'none';
        box.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="links"> 
    <li id="butt1"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('box1');">blah</a></li> 
    <li id="butt2"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('box2');">blah</a></li> 
    <li id="butt3"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('box3');">blah</a></li> 
</ul> 
    <div id="box1" style="display: none;">You clicked butt1!</div>
    <div id="box2" style="display: none;">You clicked butt2!</div> 
    <div id="box3" style="display: none;">You clicked butt3!</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is asuming that you only have one box

```
window.onload = function() {
 var links = document.getElementById("links"),
     box1  = document.getElementsByClassName("box1")[0];

 links.onclick = function() {
  links.style.display = "none";
  box1.style.display = "inline";
 };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The production compressed version of Jquery is only 31KB.  Load it through http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery .  You dont have to load the UI if you dont need it. The amount of code to do what you want isnt worth the ease in Jquery. Plus like JamWaffles said if there are other places that you will use Jquery then just load it and use it.