# Hide a div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I'm trying to hide a div on my website using javascript.

HTML :

```
<div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_39_ portlet-borderless portlet-rss  portlet-draggable yui3-dd-drop" id="p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_">
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
document.getElementById('p_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq').style.display="none";
```

I got this error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of null

I'm using Liferay by the way. Someone know where is my problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ID isn't the same as the one on the element. `id="p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_"`

Comment: Thanks, just corrected that but it still don't work. Always this message error

Comment: Please make sure you have a unique ID or else it won't work as expected.

Comment: Is your javascript executing before the document is loaded, before the div is present?

Comment: Maybe not, how can I check this ? Or there is something to execute my script before loaded the document ?

Comment: Use the debugger to stop at the line where the error is occuring. Then, in the "Elements" tab of devtools, search (Ctrl-F) for the element in question--you can do this by simple typing `#p_39...` into the search box. Most likely that element will not be found. Then you can locate the element you **did** mean to refer to, and track down inconsistency in IDs, or if you can't find it, figure out why it doesn't exist.

Comment: Found it, my script is inside the body tag and not the head. It is the reason why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript show and hide elements on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662247/javascript-show-and-hide-elements-on-click)

Answer (score 2):

Works fine in principle:

```js
function hide() {
  document.getElementById("p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_39_ portlet-borderless portlet-rss  portlet-draggable yui3-dd-drop" id="p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_">GOODBYE</div>
<button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
```

If you fix the ID to make sure it's the exact same one, the other thing to check is to make sure that the `<div>` exists by the time the JS line is called. You can do this by moving the `<script>` to the end of your `<body>`, or by wrapping the call in a handler that makes sure it's only called after all the HTML is loaded.

Comment: "Works fine" is not an answer; it's a close vote for "not reproducible" and/or a comment.

Comment: @torazaburo Edited my answer to include possible fix. I'm still learning the ins and outs of SO :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the `id` on the DIV is the same as the one you are using in your javascript, which in your case is not.

Replace this `<div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_39_ portlet-borderless portlet-rss  portlet-draggable yui3-dd-drop" id="p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_">` with this

`<div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_39_ portlet-borderless portlet-rss  portlet-draggable yui3-dd-drop" id="p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_">I AM HIDDEN</div>`.

**Javascript**
In your javascript, make sure ID are the same tho.

`document.getElementById('p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_').style.display="none";`

Comment: Are you reporting a typo? That's a close reason, possibly with a comment, to allow the OP to easily delete his/her post before it gets answers.

Answer (score 0):

Change the js to this, and also, execute the javascript code after all the elements are loaded. If you already fixed the ID, and still does not work, remember to put the script tag after all elements inside body, and just before the body closing.

```
document.getElementById('p_p_id_39_INSTANCE_gUlP5HeyQaiq_').style.display="none"
```